# jQuery: Replacing bind() with on() for many events

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, bind

Currently I have

```
$("#string").bind("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function () {

});
```

and I 'd like to replace it with `.on()` but it doesn't seem `on()` accepts many events at the same time?

I tried this:

```
$("#string").on("keyup", "keypress", "paste", "mouseup", function () {

});
```

and this:

```
$("#string").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function () {

});
```

Comment: `.on()` [supports multiple events](http://api.jquery.com/on/). What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: .on() definitely supports space seperated lists of events in the events selector (as per the documentation).  Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Check my edit please. Tried it

Comment: The latter works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb82v/

Comment: Agree with @Juhana, works fine!!

Comment: What element type is `#string`?

Comment: The problem was coming from elsewhere thats why this wasn't working. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that you can definitely use .on() with a space seperated list of events to bind multiple events: [link](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Which means that your code should work like this:

```
$("#string").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function () { 
    alert("hello!");
});
```

Here's a quick [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6kf/13/)...  Mouse up definitely works - can't confirm the other event types though (**EDIT** Just tried all your events and they definitely work - see the jsFiddle)...

Comment: the problem was coming from elsewhere thats why this wasn't working. Sorry and thanks